# Add dynamic columns to MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql, let's call it `foo` and it has a limitied amount of columns.

```
| id | name |    date    |
--------------------------
| 1  | bar  | 2012-05-08 |
| 2  | buba | 2012-05-09 |
```

My users can add records to the table `foo_field` (stuff like, `code`, `description`, `time`...).

```
| id | name        |
--------------------
| 1  | code        |
| 2  | description |
| 3  | time        |
```

In the table `foo_field_value` the values for the user-defined fields are stored, like so:

```
| id | foo_id | foo_field_id | value     |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1      | 1            | b         |
| 2  | 1      | 2            | Lalalala  |
| 3  | 1      | 3            | 12:00     |
| 1  | 2      | 1            | c         |
| 2  | 2      | 2            | We are go |
| 3  | 2      | 3            | 14:00     |
```

Ideally, I'd want one query which would give me a result like

```
| id | name | date       | code | description | time  |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | bar  | 2012-05-08 | b    | Lalalala    | 12:00 |
| 2  | buba | 2012-05-09 | c    | We are go   | 14:00 |
```

Is this even possible without doing an inner join on the foo_fields_value table for every foo_field (generating the query with PHP by doing another query first).

Comment: Can there be more than one foo_field_value for each foo record?

Comment: Yes, the pairs code = b, description = lalalal, time = 12:00 are 3 seperate records in foo_fields_value that all relate to foo record id 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do it in just one, and quite simple.

We are going to modify the foo_field table a bit, adding a column corresponding to the foo table's id column, which I assume is the primary key.

so now we have

```
* foo
|------|
| id   |
| name |
| date |
|------|

* foo_field
|-------------|
| foo_id      |
| code        |
| description |
| time        |
|-------------|
```

Which means we can add the extra fields with one simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
LEFT JOIN foo_field ON foo.id = foo_field.foo_id
```

Which will give us a result set of

```
| id | name  |       date | foo_id | code   | description |     time |
|----+-------+------------+--------+--------+-------------+----------|
|  1 | asdw  | 2012-05-16 |      1 | asdasd | asdasd      | 15:03:41 |
|  2 | fdgfe | 2012-05-18 |      2 | asdas  | asdas       | 15:03:41 |
|  3 | asdw  | 2012-05-16 |      3 | asdas  | asdas       | 15:03:52 |
|  4 | fdgfe | 2012-05-18 |      4 | asdasd | asdasd      | 15:03:52 |
```

I am still not sure I surely understood your question. If you want to create truly dynamic values and datastructures, I suggest you save a [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array into a [TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) field in your database, but I also suggest you to overlook your solution if this is the case; if you want your solution to be able to grow, you want to manage as strict structures as possible.

Comment: You misunderstood my database structure I'm afraid, I'll detail my OP more.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a pivot query. And since you have dynamic fields that need to converted to columns, check this article here about making automatic pivot queries

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#523